# Crop images with rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Долго я мучал scale и crop.

Засовываю картинку в скролл. Потом

```
- (void)doneCropping
{
    float zoomScale = 1.0 / [scrollView zoomScale];

    CGRect rect;
    rect.origin.x    =  scrollView.contentOffset.x * zoomScale;
    rect.origin.y    =  scrollView.contentOffset.y * zoomScale;
    rect.size.width  =  scrollView.bounds.size.width * zoomScale;
    rect.size.height =  scrollView.bounds.size.height * zoomScale;

    CGImageRef cr = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageView.image CGImage], rect);

    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cr];

    CGImageRelease(cr);
}
```

А вопрос мой таков: как сделать поворот этой картинки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.ImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (M_PI * corner / 180.0);
```

где `corner` - угол поворота.

Comment: Дело в том, что при таком повороте, когда я обрезаю картинку 

`CGImageRef cr = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageView.image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cr];`
Угол поворота не сохраняется (

Comment: А как должно сохраняться? В вопросе это не проясняется. Вы эту картинку хотите физически изменить и сохранить из приложения? Это уже другая тема, получается.

Comment: Есть картинка. С камеры. Я ее увеличиваю, поворачиваю на 15* и нажимаю crop, и оно должно отобразить тот сегмент, который на экране. С тем же поворотом, размером и положением.

Comment: Ясно. Вот здесь пример кода для такой ситуации:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061691/rotation-and-cropping-an-image-ios